# XML File is not displaying in a browser

Tags: xml, xslt

I created an XML document with a linked xsl file. The files passed validation but when I try to view the XML document in a browser all of the data is just strung in to a jumbled mess. I'm not sure what I'm missing. 
The XML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="EmployeeRecords.xsl"?>
<EmployeeRecords xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="EmployeeRecords.xsd">
    <employee>
        <Emp_ID>677509</Emp_ID>
        <Prefix>Drs.</Prefix>
        <FName>Lois</FName>
        <Initial>H</Initial>
        <LName>Walker</LName>
        <Gender>F</Gender>
        <Email>lois.walker@hotmail.com</Email>
        <FatherName>Donald Walker</FatherName>
        <MotherName>Helen Walker</MotherName>
        <MotherMaidenName>Lewis</MotherMaidenName>
        <DateOfBirth>3/29/1981</DateOfBirth>
        <TimeOfBirth>2:31:49 AM</TimeOfBirth>
        <Age>36.36</Age>
        <WeightKG>60</WeightKG>
        <HireDate>11/24/2003</HireDate>
        <QuarterOfJoining>Q4</QuarterOfJoining>
        <HalfOfJoining>H2</HalfOfJoining>
        <YearOfJoining>2003</YearOfJoining>
        <MonthOfJoining>11</MonthOfJoining>
        <MonthNameJoining>November</MonthNameJoining>
        <ShortMonth>Nov</ShortMonth>
        <DayOfJoining>24</DayOfJoining>
        <DOWJoining>Monday</DOWJoining>
        <ShortDOW>Mon</ShortDOW>
        <AgeInCompany>13.68</AgeInCompany>
        <Salary>168251</Salary>
        <LastPayIncrease>21%</LastPayIncrease>
        <SSN>467-99-4677</SSN>
        <Phone>303-572-8492</Phone>
        <PlaceName>Denver</PlaceName>
        <County>Denver</County>
        <City>Denver</City>
        <State>CO</State>
        <Zip>80224</Zip>
        <Region>West</Region>
        <UserName>lhwalker</UserName>
        <Password>DCa}.T}X:v?NP</Password>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <Emp_ID>940761</Emp_ID>
        <Prefix>Ms.</Prefix>
        <FName>Brenda</FName>
        <Initial>S</Initial>
        <LName>Robinson</LName>
        <Gender>F</Gender>
        <Email>brenda.robinson@gmail.com</Email>
        <FatherName>Raymond Robinson</FatherName>
        <MotherName>Judy Robinson</MotherName>
        <MotherMaidenName>Perry</MotherMaidenName>
        <DateOfBirth>7/31/1970</DateOfBirth>
        <TimeOfBirth>12:13:27 PM</TimeOfBirth>
        <Age>47.02</Age>
        <WeightKG>60</WeightKG>
        <HireDate>7/27/2008</HireDate>
        <QuarterOfJoining>Q3</QuarterOfJoining>
        <HalfOfJoining>H2</HalfOfJoining>
        <YearOfJoining>2008</YearOfJoining>
        <MonthOfJoining>7</MonthOfJoining>
        <MonthNameJoining>July</MonthNameJoining>
        <ShortMonth>Jul</ShortMonth>
        <DayOfJoining>27</DayOfJoining>
        <DOWJoining>Sunday</DOWJoining>
        <ShortDOW>Sun</ShortDOW>
        <AgeInCompany>9.01</AgeInCompany>
        <Salary>51063</Salary>
        <LastPayIncrease>27%</LastPayIncrease>
        <SSN>537-71-4566</SSN>
        <Phone>225-945-4954</Phone>
        <PlaceName>Stonewall</PlaceName>
        <County>De Soto</County>
        <City>Stonewall</City>
        <State>LA</State>
        <Zip>71078</Zip>
        <Region>South</Region>
        <UserName>bsrobinson</UserName>
        <Password>TCo\j#Zg;SQ~o</Password>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <Emp_ID>428945</Emp_ID>
        <Prefix>Dr.</Prefix>
        <FName>Joe</FName>
        <Initial>W</Initial>
        <LName>Robinson</LName>
        <Gender>M</Gender>
        <Email>joe.robinson@gmail.com</Email>
        <FatherName>Scott Robinson</FatherName>
        <MotherName>Stephanie Robinson</MotherName>
        <MotherMaidenName>Taylor</MotherMaidenName>
        <DateOfBirth>6/16/1963</DateOfBirth>
        <TimeOfBirth>10:45:36 AM</TimeOfBirth>
        <Age>54.15</Age>
        <WeightKG>68</WeightKG>
        <HireDate>8/3/2016</HireDate>
        <QuarterOfJoining>Q3</QuarterOfJoining>
        <HalfOfJoining>H2</HalfOfJoining>
        <YearOfJoining>2016</YearOfJoining>
        <MonthOfJoining>8</MonthOfJoining>
        <MonthNameJoining>August</MonthNameJoining>
        <ShortMonth>Aug</ShortMonth>
        <DayOfJoining>3</DayOfJoining>
        <DOWJoining>Wednesday</DOWJoining>
        <ShortDOW>Wed</ShortDOW>
        <AgeInCompany>0.98</AgeInCompany>
        <Salary>50155</Salary>
        <LastPayIncrease>16%</LastPayIncrease>
        <SSN>025-92-3584</SSN>
        <Phone>219-904-2161</Phone>
        <PlaceName>Michigantown</PlaceName>
        <County>Clinton</County>
        <City>Michigantown</City>
        <State>IN</State>
        <Zip>46057</Zip>
        <Region>Midwest</Region>
        <UserName>jwrobinson</UserName>
        <Password>GO4$J8MiEh[A</Password>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <Emp_ID>408351</Emp_ID>
        <Prefix>Drs.</Prefix>
        <FName>Diane</FName>
        <Initial>I</Initial>
        <LName>Evans</LName>
        <Gender>F</Gender>
        <Email>diane.evans@yahoo.com</Email>
        <FatherName>Jason Evans</FatherName>
        <MotherName>Michelle Evans</MotherName>
        <MotherMaidenName>Allen</MotherMaidenName>
        <DateOfBirth>12/4/1977</DateOfBirth>
        <TimeOfBirth>2:18:45 AM</TimeOfBirth>
        <Age>39.67</Age>
        <WeightKG>51</WeightKG>
        <HireDate>4/16/1999</HireDate>
        <QuarterOfJoining>Q2</QuarterOfJoining>
        <HalfOfJoining>H1</HalfOfJoining>
        <YearOfJoining>1999</YearOfJoining>
        <MonthOfJoining>4</MonthOfJoining>
        <MonthNameJoining>April</MonthNameJoining>
        <ShortMonth>Apr</ShortMonth>
        <DayOfJoining>16</DayOfJoining>
        <DOWJoining>Friday</DOWJoining>
        <ShortDOW>Fri</ShortDOW>
        <AgeInCompany>18.3</AgeInCompany>
        <Salary>180294</Salary>
        <LastPayIncrease>1%</LastPayIncrease>
        <SSN>314-35-9851</SSN>
        <Phone>215-793-6791</Phone>
        <PlaceName>Hydetown</PlaceName>
        <County>Crawford</County>
        <City>Hydetown</City>
        <State>PA</State>
        <Zip>16328</Zip>
        <Region>Northeast</Region>
        <UserName>dievans</UserName>
        <Password>0gGRtp1HfLr5
            </Password>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <Emp_ID>193819</Emp_ID>
        <Prefix>Mr.</Prefix>
        <FName>Benjamin</FName>
        <Initial>R</Initial>
        <LName>Russell</LName>
        <Gender>M</Gender>
        <Email>benjamin.russell@charter.net</Email>
        <FatherName>Gregory Russell</FatherName>
        <MotherName>Elizabeth Russell</MotherName>
        <MotherMaidenName>Nelson</MotherMaidenName>
        <DateOfBirth>4/17/1977</DateOfBirth>
        <TimeOfBirth>5:41:11 PM</TimeOfBirth>
        <Age>40.31</Age>
        <WeightKG>58</WeightKG>
        <HireDate>7/25/2013</HireDate>
        <QuarterOfJoining>Q3</QuarterOfJoining>
        <HalfOfJoining>H2</HalfOfJoining>
        <YearOfJoining>2013</YearOfJoining>
        <MonthOfJoining>7</MonthOfJoining>
        <MonthNameJoining>July</MonthNameJoining>
        <ShortMonth>Jul</ShortMonth>
        <DayOfJoining>25</DayOfJoining>
        <DOWJoining>Thursday</DOWJoining>
        <ShortDOW>Thu</ShortDOW>
        <AgeInCompany>4.01</AgeInCompany>
        <Salary>117642</Salary>
        <LastPayIncrease>13%</LastPayIncrease>
        <SSN>121-98-7248</SSN>
        <Phone>262-404-2252</Phone>
        <PlaceName>Fremont</PlaceName>
        <County>Waupaca</County>
        <City>Fremont</City>
        <State>WI</State>
        <Zip>54940</Zip>
        <Region>Midwest</Region>
        <UserName>brrussell</UserName>
        <Password>RdY8cp!@R;*%F

            </Password>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <Emp_ID>499687</Emp_ID>
        <Prefix>Mr.</Prefix>
        <FName>Patrick</FName>
        <Initial>F</Initial>
        <LName>Bailey</LName>
        <Gender>M</Gender>
        <Email>patrick.bailey@aol.com</Email>
        <FatherName>Ralph Bailey</FatherName>
        <MotherName>Laura Bailey</MotherName>
        <MotherMaidenName>Henderson</MotherMaidenName>
        <DateOfBirth>9/27/1982</DateOfBirth>
        <TimeOfBirth>1:12:41 PM</TimeOfBirth>
        <Age>34.86</Age>
        <WeightKG>58</WeightKG>
        <HireDate>7/22/2005</HireDate>
        <QuarterOfJoining>Q3</QuarterOfJoining>
        <HalfOfJoining>H2</HalfOfJoining>
        <YearOfJoining>2005</YearOfJoining>
        <MonthOfJoining>7</MonthOfJoining>
        <MonthNameJoining>July</MonthNameJoining>
        <ShortMonth>Jul</ShortMonth>
        <DayOfJoining>22</DayOfJoining>
        <DOWJoining>Friday</DOWJoining>
        <ShortDOW>Fri</ShortDOW>
        <AgeInCompany>12.02</AgeInCompany>
        <Salary>72305</Salary>
        <LastPayIncrease>5%</LastPayIncrease>
        <SSN>439-99-7721</SSN>
        <Phone>319-812-6957</Phone>
        <PlaceName>Macksburg</PlaceName>
        <County>Madison</County>
        <City>Macksburg</City>
        <State>IA</State>
        <Zip>50155</Zip>
        <Region>Midwest</Region>
        <UserName>pfbailey</UserName>
        <Password>K755aY/*</Password>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <Emp_ID>539712</Emp_ID>
        <Prefix>Ms.</Prefix>
        <FName>Nancy</FName>
        <Initial>T</Initial>
        <LName>Baker</LName>
        <Gender>F</Gender>
        <Email>nancy.baker@bp.com</Email>
        <FatherName>Scott Baker</FatherName>
        <MotherName>Judy Baker</MotherName>
        <MotherMaidenName>Thomas</MotherMaidenName>
        <DateOfBirth>6/13/1995</DateOfBirth>
        <TimeOfBirth>8:56:32 PM</TimeOfBirth>
        <Age>22.14</Age>
        <WeightKG>50</WeightKG>
        <HireDate>9/14/2016</HireDate>
        <QuarterOfJoining>Q3</QuarterOfJoining>
        <HalfOfJoining>H2</HalfOfJoining>
        <YearOfJoining>2016</YearOfJoining>
        <MonthOfJoining>9</MonthOfJoining>
        <MonthNameJoining>September</MonthNameJoining>
        <ShortMonth>Sep</ShortMonth>
        <DayOfJoining>14</DayOfJoining>
        <DOWJoining>Wednesday</DOWJoining>
        <ShortDOW>Wed</ShortDOW>
        <AgeInCompany>0.87</AgeInCompany>
        <Salary>98189</Salary>
        <LastPayIncrease>0%</LastPayIncrease>
        <SSN>641-29-2071</SSN>
        <Phone>229-336-5117</Phone>
        <PlaceName>Atlanta</PlaceName>
        <County>Fulton</County>
        <City>Atlanta</City>
        <State>GA</State>
        <Zip>30334</Zip>
        <Region>South</Region>
        <UserName>ntbaker</UserName>
        <Password>xJdKlAcYQhT_BE#</Password>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <Emp_ID>380086</Emp_ID>
        <Prefix>Mrs.</Prefix>
        <FName>Carol</FName>
        <Initial>V</Initial>
        <LName>Murphy</LName>
        <Gender>F</Gender>
        <Email>carol.murphy@gmail.com</Email>
        <FatherName>Eugene Murphy</FatherName>
        <MotherName>Katherine Murphy</MotherName>
        <MotherMaidenName>Peterson</MotherMaidenName>
        <DateOfBirth>6/30/1958</DateOfBirth>
        <TimeOfBirth>10:39:33 AM</TimeOfBirth>
        <Age>59.12</Age>
        <WeightKG>40</WeightKG>
        <HireDate>1/28/1983</HireDate>
        <QuarterOfJoining>Q1</QuarterOfJoining>
        <HalfOfJoining>H1</HalfOfJoining>
        <YearOfJoining>1983</YearOfJoining>
        <MonthOfJoining>1</MonthOfJoining>
        <MonthNameJoining>January</MonthNameJoining>
        <ShortMonth>Jan</ShortMonth>
        <DayOfJoining>28</DayOfJoining>
        <DOWJoining>Friday</DOWJoining>
        <ShortDOW>Fri</ShortDOW>
        <AgeInCompany>34.52</AgeInCompany>
        <Salary>60918</Salary>
        <LastPayIncrease>20%</LastPayIncrease>
        <SSN>423-67-7023</SSN>
        <Phone>216-336-0009</Phone>
        <PlaceName>Blanchester</PlaceName>
        <County>Clinton</County>
        <City>Blanchester</City>
        <State>OH</State>
        <Zip>45107</Zip>
        <Region>Midwest</Region>
        <UserName>cvmurphy</UserName>
        <Password>Uc+VG%vuZU5k



            </Password>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <Emp_ID>477616</Emp_ID>
        <Prefix>Hon.</Prefix>
        <FName>Frances</FName>
        <Initial>B</Initial>
        <LName>Young</LName>
        <Gender>F</Gender>
        <Email>frances.young@gmail.com</Email>
        <FatherName>Fred Young</FatherName>
        <MotherName>Lillian Young</MotherName>
        <MotherMaidenName>Diaz</MotherMaidenName>
        <DateOfBirth>6/9/1959</DateOfBirth>
        <TimeOfBirth>4:38:47 PM</TimeOfBirth>
        <Age>58.18</Age>
        <WeightKG>42</WeightKG>
        <HireDate>4/27/1994</HireDate>
        <QuarterOfJoining>Q2</QuarterOfJoining>
        <HalfOfJoining>H1</HalfOfJoining>
        <YearOfJoining>1994</YearOfJoining>
        <MonthOfJoining>4</MonthOfJoining>
        <MonthNameJoining>April</MonthNameJoining>
        <ShortMonth>Apr</ShortMonth>
        <DayOfJoining>27</DayOfJoining>
        <DOWJoining>Wednesday</DOWJoining>
        <ShortDOW>Wed</ShortDOW>
        <AgeInCompany>23.27</AgeInCompany>
        <Salary>121587</Salary>
        <LastPayIncrease>28%</LastPayIncrease>
        <SSN>028-92-8912</SSN>
        <Phone>210-819-9765</Phone>
        <PlaceName>Delmita</PlaceName>
        <County>Starr</County>
        <City>Delmita</City>
        <State>TX</State>
        <Zip>78536</Zip>
        <Region>South</Region>
        <UserName>fbyoung</UserName>
        <Password>K}^USc0l7[A</Password>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <Emp_ID>162402</Emp_ID>
        <Prefix>Hon.</Prefix>
        <FName>Diana</FName>
        <Initial>T</Initial>
        <LName>Peterson</LName>
        <Gender>F</Gender>
        <Email>diana.peterson@hotmail.co.uk</Email>
        <FatherName>Jonathan Peterson</FatherName>
        <MotherName>Christina Peterson</MotherName>
        <MotherMaidenName>Ross</MotherMaidenName>
        <DateOfBirth>11/13/1987</DateOfBirth>
        <TimeOfBirth>3:59:26 AM</TimeOfBirth>
        <Age>29.73</Age>
        <WeightKG>60</WeightKG>
        <HireDate>2/17/2014</HireDate>
        <QuarterOfJoining>Q1</QuarterOfJoining>
        <HalfOfJoining>H1</HalfOfJoining>
        <YearOfJoining>2014</YearOfJoining>
        <MonthOfJoining>2</MonthOfJoining>
        <MonthNameJoining>February</MonthNameJoining>
        <ShortMonth>Feb</ShortMonth>
        <DayOfJoining>17</DayOfJoining>
        <DOWJoining>Monday</DOWJoining>
        <ShortDOW>Mon</ShortDOW>
        <AgeInCompany>3.44</AgeInCompany>
        <Salary>43010</Salary>
        <LastPayIncrease>4%</LastPayIncrease>
        <SSN>512-33-6767</SSN>
        <Phone>479-783-5656</Phone>
        <PlaceName>Eureka Springs</PlaceName>
        <County>Carroll</County>
        <City>Eureka Springs</City>
        <State>AR</State>
        <Zip>72632</Zip>
        <Region>South</Region>
        <UserName>dtpeterson</UserName>
        <Password>3o8>v3tYxjyEAo</Password>
    </employee>
</EmployeeRecords>
```

The xsl code I have is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Employee Records</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Employee Records</h1>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#00b3b" >
            <th>Employee_ID</th>
            <th>Prefix</th>
            <th>FName</th>
            <th>Initial</th>
            <th>LName</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>FatherName</th>
            <th>MotherName</th>
            <th>MotherMaidenName</th>
            <th>DateOfBirth</th>
            <th>TimeOfBirth</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>WeightKG</th>
            <th>HireDate</th>
            <th>QuarterOfJoining</th>
            <th>HalfOfJoining</th>
            <th>YearOfJoining</th>
            <th>MonthOfJoining</th>
            <th>MonthNameJoining</th>
            <th>ShortMonth</th>
            <th>DayOfJoining</th>
            <th>DOWJoining</th>
            <th>ShortDOW</th>
            <th>AgeInCompany </th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>LastPayIncrease</th>
            <th>SSN</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>PlaceName</th>
            <th>County</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State </th>
            <th>Zip</th>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>Password</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="Employee">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Employee_ID"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Prefix"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="FName"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Initial"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="LName"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Gender"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Email"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="FatherName"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="MotherName"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="MotherMaidenName"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="DateOfBirth"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="TimeOfBirth"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Age"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="WeightKG"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="HireDate"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="QuarterOfJoining"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="HalfOfJoining"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="YearOfJoining"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="MonthOfJoining"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="MonthName"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="ShortMonth"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="DayOfJoining"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="DOWJoining"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="ShortDOW"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="AgeInCompany"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Salary"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="LastPayIncrease"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="SSN"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Phone"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="PlaceName"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="County"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="City"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="State"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Zip"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Region"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="UserName"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Password"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Again, the documents are validated but not displaying. I'm not seeing what I'm missing or know why it's not displaying correctly.

Comment: Which browser? Are you loading the XML document over HTTP(S)? Or directly from the file system? Chrome, Chromium based browsers, even Mozilla browers do not support XSLT referenced via `?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"` in XML documents loaded from the local file system any more. Also, what does the browser console (F12) show as warnings or errros?

Comment: With the XML presented, I think instead of `xsl:for-each select="EmployeeRecords/Employee"` you want `xsl:for-each select="Employee"`.